# Add xact_abort to connection string

Tags: sql-server, scala, jdbc, connection-string, mssql-jdbc

In my code I have the control over the connection string and I'm wondering if and how to add a flag of XACT_ABORT to my connection string.
i'm wondering if and how is it possible.

f.e. this is the connection string:
s"jdbc:sqlserver://$url:$port;database=$db;user=$user;password=$password;trustServerCertificate=true"

Comment: You need to set this in your batch(es); there is no connection property for it.

Comment: I've no idea why your question's title is "SQL Server BCP" when you then show a JDBC connection string. `bcp` does not use JDBC to connect.

Comment: We have a Scala (run on JVM of course) Flink app that uses Microsoft mssql-jdbc driver and implements BCP.
You can learn about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: That isn't `bcp` though...

Comment: It's isn't official BulkCopy Program utility, you are right about that, but it is the SQLserver implementation to BCP that offers the similar functionality. 
That's why i mentioned BCP :)